# Can't checkout from Version Control Git with SSH (Ciphers, MACs, KexAlgorithmsc)

Tags: git, android-studio, ssh

I've some trouble with cloning a git repo from my dedicated server,

```
14:19:28.522: cd C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects
14:19:28.523: git -c core.quotepath=false clone --progress git@host:git.git zaezaezaeaeae
Cloning into 'zaezaezaeaeae'...
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to host:port
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:791)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:577)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:137)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:92)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:230)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:743)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not match.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.handleMessage(KexManager.java:413)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:754)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:469)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The thing is i can clone my repo with command line (git clone) but on an IDE i can't and when i comment this line on my sshd_config

```
#Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
#MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
#KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

The checkout from android studio is successful, anyone has some idea how I can tell to android-studio to accept or add additional crypt mod or something like that? Or I'm totally wrong

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I have disabling the three lines in my sshd_config

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Change from built-in to Native and give your native git path. this should work.

This you should if git pull is working from your terminal and not from android studio plugin

Comment: Thanks, for this solution :D

Comment: Voila, worked for WebStorm under Mac. Thanks a bunch!